# adding visual studio XAML Intellisense to non-wpf classes

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, intellisense

I have "DOM like" data structure in c# (parent, childNodes, properties, enums...) and I want to use xml\xaml file to some of the initializing. I already wrote a tool that transform my xaml to c# and inject them in the right place.

I want the exact Intellisense behavior of WPF except that my classes doesn't inherits from WPF base classes and my project in not wpf application on library and doesn't reference wpf assemblies. i also don't want to use xsd schema because classes are added and edited very frequently.

I'm using visual studio 2010

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Create a xaml (start by creating a resource dictionary and delete the content).

Add your own assembly as the default namespace and start using your types. I have created a test for sample data recently, here's how it looks like:

```
<MainViewModel xmlns="clr-namespace:MvvmTest.ViewModels.DesignTime"
               Name="The design time main view model">
    <MainViewModel.SubViewModels>
        <FirstSubViewModel Name="The design time first sub-view model" />
        <SecondSubViewModel Name="The design time second sub-view model" />
    </MainViewModel.SubViewModels>
</MainViewModel>
```

You can load the file using the [XamlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xaml.xamlreader.aspx) class. As a bonus compared to xml, the file will be compiled and run time loading will be much faster.